# Kotlin: succinct way of inverting Int sign depending on Boolean value

Tags: kotlin

I have

```
var x: Int
var invert: Boolean
```

and I need the value of the expression

```
if (invert) -x else x
```

Is there any more succinct way to write that expression in Kotlin?

Comment: `if (invert) -x else x` is not succinct enough for you?

Comment: Well, it looks less succinct when x itself is a longer expression which ends up getting repeated twice - and Kotlin has spoiled me in terms of how short everything can be written :)

Comment: In that case you can do `someLongExpression.let { x -> if (invert) -x else x }`.

Comment: Or `val x = someLongExpression` and then use your code above.

Answer (score 3):

There is no shorter expression using only the stdlib to my knowledge.

This is pretty clear, though. Using custom functions to make it shorter is possible, but it would only obscure the meaning IMO.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell which approach might be best without seeing more of the code, but one option is an extension function. For example:

```
fun Int.negateIf(condition: Boolean) = if (condition) -this else this
```

(I'm using the term ‘negate’ here, as that's less ambiguous: when dealing with numbers, I think ‘inverse’ more often refers to a *multiplicative* inverse, i.e. reciprocal.)

You could then use:

```
x.negateIf(invert)
```

I think that makes the meaning very clear, and saves a few characters. (The saving is greater if `x` is a long name or an expression, of course.)

---

If `invert` didn't change (e.g. if it were a `val`), another option would be to derive a multiplier from it, e.g.:

```
val multiplier = if (invert) -1 else 1
```

Then you could simply multiply by that:

```
x * multiplier
```

That's even shorter, though a little less clear; if you did that, it would be worth adding a comment to explain it.

---

(BTW, whichever approach you use, there's an extremely rare corner case here: no positive Int has the same magnitude as `Int.MIN_VALUE` (-2147483648), so you can't negate that one value. Either way, you'll get that same number back. There's no easy way around that, but it's worth being aware of.)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a local extension function.

[Local functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#local-functions) are helpful when you want to reduce some repetitive code *and* you want to access a local variable (in this case, the `invert` boolean).

Local functions are particularly useful when paired with [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions), as extension functions only have one 'receiver' - so it would be difficult, or repetitive, to access `invert` if `invert()` wasn't a local function.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val x = 1
    val y = 2
    val z = 3

    var invert = false

    // this local function can still access 'invert'    
    fun Int.invert(): Int = if (invert) -this else this

    println("invert=$invert -> (${x.invert()}, ${y.invert()}, ${z.invert()})")

    invert = true

    println("invert=$invert  -> (${x.invert()}, ${y.invert()}, ${z.invert()})")
}
```

[*Run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/oHkyNQD2g)

```
invert=false -> (1, 2, 3)
invert=true  -> (-1, -2, -3)
```